# Sqlite DB column order issue on Android

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

My app works (generate a code and a relative barcode from some user's data in input), but I wanted to store data in a Db with sqlite. This is my DatabaseOpenHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cf_db.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "cf_table";
    public static final String CF = "CF";
    public static final String COL1 = "Name";
    public static final String COL2 = "Surname";
    public static final String COL3 = "Sex";
    public static final String COL4 = "Birthday";
    public static final String COL5 = "PlaceOfBirth";


    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        //SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + CF + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + COL1 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COL2 + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COL3 + "TEXT NOT NULL," + COL4 +
                "TEXT NOT NULL," + COL5 + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String cf, String name, String surname, String sex, String year,
                              String month, String day, String place) {
        String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(CF, cf);
        contentValues.put(COL1, name);
        contentValues.put(COL2, surname);
        contentValues.put(COL3, sex);
        contentValues.put(COL4, date);
        contentValues.put(COL5, place);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();

    }
}
```

There is something wrong with the insert statement at the end. I got below error:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table cf_table has no column named Birthday
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Birthday=22/08/21 CF=GGUTUU21M22I754G Surname= ggu Name=uut Sex=M PlaceOfBirth=Siracusa
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table cf_table has no column named Birthday (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cf_table(Birthday,CF,Surname,Name,Sex,PlaceOfBirth) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:901)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:512)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
                      at com.example.valerio.androidcodesgenerator.DatabaseOpenHelper.insertData(DatabaseOpenHelper.java:53)
                      at com.example.valerio.androidcodesgenerator.MainActivity.AddData(MainActivity.java:136)
                      at com.example.valerio.androidcodesgenerator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                      at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                      at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25883)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

The columns are in a random order that I don't understand, and when I used some print statement to analyze the issue I realized that the various contentValues has no value at all. I just did

```
Log.d("code", contentValues.getAsString(cf))
```

And the error was like "println needs something to print", so basically the put statement of the contentValues doesn't put anything in. In fact in the error message the values are (??????)...
In the call instead the print tests goes well and the various editText and textView have their proper content.

This is the insertData call:

```
public void AddData() {
    boolean inserted = myDb.insertData(textView_cf.getText().toString(),
        editText_name.getText().toString(),
        editText_surname.getText().toString(),
        editText_sex.getText().toString(),
        editText_aa.getText().toString(),
        editText_mm.getText().toString(),
        editText_gg.getText().toString(),
        autoCompleteTextView_place.getText().toString());
}
```

(I also need a boolean control over the insertion, but the insertion just doesn't happen right now)

Maybe it's newbie errors but I'm just new at Android Studio and not a Java expert at all...

Comment: sir,use ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + CF + "TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + COL1 + "TEXT NOT NULL,  " + COL2 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL3 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL4 + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL5 + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

Comment: @Valerio can you please assign Table create query to a string and print it in logcat

Comment: You should do Log.d("code", contentValues.getAsString(CF)) not cf

Comment: Yeah sorry the Log.d works so the contentValues works.

Comment: Is the table created? can you confirm that?

Comment: So there are problems with the Insert statement or with the table's creation. @GeorgePJ I don't understand your answer sorry, what should I print?

Comment: How can I confirm the table creation? The db is surely here, it's in the device explorer.

Comment: Did you make the changes as others suggested in the CREATE TABLE statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you must do is uninstall the app from the emulator/device where you test it and then run it again to recreate the database. If it still shows the error about the `Birthday` field then the problem is somewhere else.

Use this insert method:

```
public boolean insertData(String cf, String name, String surname, String sex, String year,
                          String month, String day, String place) {
    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(CF, cf);
    contentValues.put(COL1, name);
    contentValues.put(COL2, surname);
    contentValues.put(COL3, sex);
    contentValues.put(COL4, date);
    contentValues.put(COL5, place);
    int id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();

    return (id != -1);

}
```

I'm not sure that this will solve the problem, but by the signature of the method it must return boolean.

Comment: Thank you that worked, maybe some cache problem. Now there is no error in storing, but there are no records if i Browse Data with DB browser for Sqlite. Looking for some software documentation but I can't find why

Comment: if insertData returns true then rows are inserted. Just make a select statement and try it in your app and output to log

Comment: Done, the db works. I probably can't see anything with Db Browser because the Virtual Device is not rooted (?). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing spaces in your CREATE TABLE statement

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + 
    CF   + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + 
    COL1 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    COL3 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
    COL4 + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    COL5 + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
```